# Get generated id for related JPA entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my project I have something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Refund {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Payment payment;

    // ... other fields...
}

@Entity
public class Payment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "payment")
    private List<Refund> refunds;
    
    // ... other fields...
}
```

`Payment` is the aggregate root and when I need to add a new `Refund` I use this logic:

```
Payment payment = // fetch or create a Payment
    

Refund refund = // create + populate new Refund
refund.setPayment(payment);

payment.getRefunds().add(refund);
paymentRepository.save(payment); // <= here I'm using a Spring Data JPA repository
```

After saving `payment` I'd like to retrieve the id of the newly created `Refund`, but the `id` field is not populated in `refund` instance.

**NOTES**

- The method implementing the save logic is annotated with `@Transactional`.
- I also tried to use repo `saveAndFlush` method but nothing changes...

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use a jpa query where after saving, you are retrieving the refund by ordering them in desc order . or you want to avoid this extra step ?

Comment: Could you show the entire method?
From where are you calling the method?

Answer (score 1):

The id is available on the value returned from `save`.
In your case, the merge operation is cascaded to the collection of Refunds, and the updated refund will be available in the collection from returned payment.

Having said that, if your goal is only to add a Refund to the DB, you may prefer to save the Refund instead - it is the owning side of the relation.

See javadoc for [CrudRepository.save](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-)

> `<S extends T> S save(S entity)`
>
> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to update the payment object upon the call to the save method. What you need to do is to update to the following:

```java
payment = paymentRepository.save(payment);
```

After this, you should be able to see the IDs set, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> paymentRepository.save(payment)

should return the saved instance *payment.*

From there you can access your refunds and get the id.